# Does Transactional Email Journey return tracking back to Sales cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I tried to explore the new feature of July 2020 release i.e., [Journey Builder: Transactional Sending](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/demo-transactional-send-email-journeys-from-journey-vishal-kumar-c-v/?trackingId=lA17sQH0R%2B6rjrvQGeZf2A%3D%3D)

I am aware that Triggered Emails created in SFMC [TSD] cannot be Tracked back in Sales cloud under IER.

Salesforce help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_track_triggered_sends.htm&type=5

**Can anyone confirm** is this the same for this 'Transactional Email Journeys'? I have tested this for a Contact record but does NOT show the email name under Individual Email Results :(

Also I noticed there is NO checkbox under Email activity,
'SEND TRACKING to Sales CLOUD', as we have it under multi-step Journey!

> So the only way of tracking Triggered emails under IER is by using FireEntry API journey? or can this we achieved by other way?

More details: We need to trigger the emails from external web application [hosting our company website] using REST API to trigger email from SFMC. And SFMC in connected to Sales cloud via MCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm, that at the moment it isn't possible to get tracking results back to sales cloud via IER records, etc. when using the Transactional Send Journeys (Transactional Messaging API).

I also discussed this with the product manager responsible for the Transactional Send Journeys at Salesforce. He confirmed, that it isn't possible but *on their roadmap*. Prior to that discussion I also created an [idea for that on IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000le97QAA).

Options to have tracking right now:

- Standard tracking with IER: Multi-Step Journey with API Event
- Custom tracking (requires quite some development effort): Observe events for the transactional sends via the Event Notification Service and write them to sales cloud in a custom implementation (non standard approach)

Further reading about the Event Notification Service (ENS) can be found here: [Transactional Send Journeys and the Event Notification Service](https://markus.codes/2020/11/26/salesforce-marketing-cloud-transactional-send-journeys-event-notification-service)

Comment: Thanks Markus for adding this update and sharing additional details.

Comment: @Markus - does the Event Notification Service only work for the Transactional Messaging API or can it work for other email types in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: @AntonioDePalma At this time these are the only types of sends supported. You can find the supported events here: [SFMC Documentation - Supported Notification Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ens-supported-events.html)

Answer (score 1):

@vishal, if you place the TriggeredSend DE in the Salesforce Data Extension folder, the tracking data is sent back to Sales/ Service Cloud.

Comment: Wow really. Ok I will try this and confirm back. Thanks @Ali

Comment: Hi Ali, can you please share the steps you followed to achieve Sync using Triggered send?...... I tested for both Triggered Sends and Transactional Sends Journey in both case I was unable to sync tracking back to Sales cloud :-|

Comment: Here are the steps.  
PreReq: MC Connect integration is in place and Salesforce Data Extensions folder is available.  
1. Create a Data Extension based on template "TriggeredSendDataExtension" in Data Extension folder.  
2. Create TriggeredSend Definition and configure the Data Extension created in Step 1.  
3. Move the Data Extension created in Step 1 into Salesforce Data Extension folder.  
4. Send the email using the SFID as Subscriber Key and TriggeredSend Definition created in Step 2.  
5. Wait for 60-90 minutes and check Service Cloud in Individual Email Results object or tab.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV, did this process worked for you? I am trying to confirm because I follow all the steps but didn't work for me.

Comment: @AliMushaf, I followed your process with both a TriggeredSend Definition and a Journey, the emails are being sent but I haven't been able to see the emails in SF "Individual Email Results". Is it possible there is any step missing? Thanks in advanced

Comment: @Leo I confirm that I was UNABLE to sync the tracking data, in-spite of placing the DE in Salesforce Data Extension folder :(

Comment: @VishalKumarCV, thank you for your response. That's what I suspected. I was able to sync the data by switching to a multipart journey, triggering an Entry Event as you noted in your original post. So, thank you for that.

Comment: @Leo welcome :)